# SharePoint Lookup Column Additional Field Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, lookup-column, filter

Hello SharePoint Community!

So, I have a list of a `item content type` that has a Yes/No field. I reference this content type in a lookup relationship on a Document Library. From that lookup relationship I want to get the value of the Yes/No field.

> Now I know that Choice fields are not allowed as lookup columns. So I created a calculated "single line text" field on the content type that strings out the value of my Yes/No field.
>
> This calculated field works fine and well on the Item list. (If Column is checked the value of the calculated field changes to "Yes")...

Then on my document library when I look at my lookup field related [Additional] columns, I can see and select my work around Yes/No item text field! Awesome!

**Problem**:

1. The value that is shelled out on to the document library is not "Yes" or "No"... It's '1' or '0' respectively.

> Which would not bother me really too much, but for number 2...

2. The document library filter wont allow me to filter based on my `calculated-related-lookup-column` in any way that makes since.

> I tride:
>
> > item:col [equal to] {1, 0, "1", "0"}
> >
> > item:col [equal to] {Yes, YES, yes}
> >
> > item:col [equal to] {True, TRUE, true}
>
> Using [grater than] or [less than] gives some less than veried results...

I even thought about trying the ASCII integer values...

I am out of ideas. All I really want to do, is be able to filter on my wacky `calculated-related-lookup-column`. I don't care that it doesn't actually say Yes or No, but am wondering if that is a symptom to the solution of the problem!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a little more testing. I was able to figure out it has something to do with a Yes/No "Calculated" field, and a Choice "Calculated" field.

Yes/No will give some boolean typed answer when looked up, but the filter does not know what to do with it.

A Choice will always be converted to a String which can be compared to. So I just created a Choice field on my Content Type and replicated the scenario and it works!

I would still be curious if any one can tell me what the Boolean lookup issue I was having before is.

Thanks!